# Detecting whether a remote computer is a Domain Controller

Tags: windows, domaincontroller

My workplace has several lab environments, each with a bunch of Windows servers.  Users generally access the servers via the Administrator accounts for problem solving or training.  I am interested in determining which servers, if any, have been set up as domain controllers by people using the labs.  None of these DCs will have any trust relationships with the machine I plan to use for scanning.  There's too many servers for me to RDP to each, and it's very likely that any given domain will have only itself or a very few other servers as domain members.  Google has turned up some penetration testing blogs that have some techniques, but they seem like overkill for my needs.  Ideally, I would like to scan all the machines in a given subnet for an open port or something and then RDP to just the positive hits to check out the details.

Comment: Off the top of my head, I believe the LDAP service runs on port 3389.  At any rate, it's well documented.

Comment: Thanks, that was just enough information for Google to find the answer.  (It's actually 389, and 636 for SSL.  https://support.microsoft.com/kb/224447/EN-US)

Comment: Oh, right, 3389 is Remote Desktop - my mistake.